# java.lang.NullPointerException when setting icon?

Tags: java

I've recently tried to set my default application icon with a .ico file I made myself. This is the code I used to create the icon:

```
initComponents();
java.net.URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("/src/calculatormedii/resources/CMedii.ico");
Toolkit kit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
Image img = kit.createImage(url);
getFrame().setIconImage(img);
```

I have no idea why it's so difficult to set the java desktop application icon in netbeans, it should just be a property field like the rest.
   When I try to run the program, these errors show up:

```
    Uncaught error fetching image:
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getConnection(URLImageSource.java:99)
    at sun.awt.image.URLImageSource.getDecoder(URLImageSource.java:113)
    at sun.awt.image.InputStreamImageSource.doFetch(InputStreamImageSource.java:240)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.fetchloop(ImageFetcher.java:172)
    at sun.awt.image.ImageFetcher.run(ImageFetcher.java:136)
```

No idea what to do now. If there is an alternate way to set the application icon please specify it (Like a property field in netbeans or something)

Comment: Are you sure you have a `src` folder/package in your application? I don't mean the sources folder you compile from but a folder in the compiled application.

Comment: OK. This problem has been fixed. The problem wasn't the path or anything. As Jon Skeet gave me that set code, I used it and the icon remained the default. 

  The problem was that my file was an ICO file. I converted a 16X16 version of my icon and saved it as PNG then added it to resources, and that fixed my problem.

 Thanks alot guys, StackOverflow is a gem in the programming field, I got my answer in less than a minute!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I strongly suspect it's the URL you're using. Using `ClassLoader.getSystemResource`, you shouldn't need a leading slash - but I very much doubt that you want the `src` part either. You should make sure that your icon is copied to the same place that your class files is (e.g. a `bin` directory) and then just use:

```
URL url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("calculatormedii/resources/CMedii.ico");
```

Comment: OK I moved the icon file to that folder, and it doesn't show any errors now, however the icon hasn't changed. It's still the coffee cup java apps have. Any help? I moved the icon in 2 spots: The bin folder and the folder all the other classes are.

Comment: I assume he even doesn't want the `calculatormedii/` part.

Comment: @Thomas: Sounds like that *is* part of the tree, given that the error's gone away.

Comment: @user1115506: Perhaps the `ico` format isn't supported by the classes you're using? I can't say I know much about that side of things.

Comment: Yes indeed, thanks Jon Skeet. I do have suspicions that the ico files are not supported, as I tried setting them before as an "Import image" in netbeans and it didn't allow it. I'll try convert it to png and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You shall print more of your stack trace. If you look further down, you will find the caller line inside your code that leads to the exception in java librairies.

But in your case, the problem comes from the fact that the path you give to getSystemResource as a parameter should be relative to the folder containing the actual class file of the class you are coding in.

More precisely, you can use both :

- ClassLoader.getSystemResource and then the path has to be relative to your classpath entries
- getClass.getResourceUrl and the the path has to be relative to the class file of class you are coding in.
- X.class.getResourceUrl and the the path has to be relative to the class file of class X.

If you use eclipse with maven, a default folder structure is to have

```
 /src/main/java
 /src/main/resources
```

And then everything is handled for you : copying the resources files inside the same folder as the java files are compiled to.

Comment: When I add the relative path where classes are the errors come up again. I tried setting about 5 paths at the moment, if I change anything besides Jon Skeet's answer it shows those 5 errors.

Comment: Please detail what you try. Also, how do you get sure resource is copied in the folder where you class files are located. Try to copy them manually after compiling. Put you ico file in the file where you class file is and use a folder-less path to access the ico file.